# How to merge state and props passed to a smart component from parent smart component in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and redux.  Here in the App.React.js I'm passing onRouteChange as props to Post.js. In Post.js, in the redux connect, I  receive the state from store and ownprops. I think ownprops will be hold all the props passed to the component by the parent component. But I'm not receiving the onRouteChange in Post.js. Please help me. What I'm missing?

App.React.js

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onNavigatorRef = this.onNavigatorRef.bind(this);
   this.onRouteChange = this.onRouteChange.bind(this);
   this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this);
}

onRouteChange(route, toggleSideMenu = true) {
   this.navigator.jumpTo(routes[route]);
   if (toggleSideMenu) {
      this.props.toggleSideMenu();
   }
}

renderScene(route) {
    const { isSideMenuOpen, toggleSideMenu } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={[styles.sceneView, route.style]}>
        <StatusBar hidden={isSideMenuOpen} />
        <Header onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        <route.Page onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Post.js

```
export default connect(
(state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(`ownprops=${JSON.stringify(ownProps)}`); //{}
  console.log(`ownprops=${ownProps.onRouteChange}`);   //undefined
  return {
    posts: state.posts.map,
    onRouteChange: ownProps.onRouteChange,
    ...ownProps
  };
}, 
(dispatch, ownProps) => {
    console.log(`ownprops=${JSON.stringify(dispatch)}`); //{}
    console.log(`ownprops=${JSON.stringify(ownProps)}`); //{}
    console.log(`ownprops=${ownProps.onRouteChange}`); //undefined
    return {
      postsActions,
      onRouteChange: ownProps.onRouteChange,
      ...ownProps
    };
})(Posts);
```

Comment: Don't see how you are passing `onRouteChange` to **Post.js**.  I can see only how you are passing `onRouteChange` to `<Header>`  and `<route.Page>` components. Which of them is  defined in **Post.js**?

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to say that usually it's not a good practice to connect Child components to Redux. You should only connect the high level components to Redux and pass props to the "dumb" components.

As for your question, according to [Redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments):

> [mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function): If specified, the component will subscribe to Redux store updates. Any time it updates, mapStateToProps will be called. Its result must be a plain object*, and it will be merged into the component’s props

This means, you should only add here props that are not coming from parent.
mapStateToProps is used to add aditional props you want from state. The props you receive from parent are intact - unless you override them.
(In your case you are overriding them in the mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProp, but with the same ownProps received from parent, so it doesn't matter.)
In your example you say you pass the onRouteChange to Posts, but it's not shown, you may be passing it to the route.Page or to some Parent component, but it's not shown here. Wherever you create the posts component, you should add the onRouteChange there.

```
<Posts onRouteChange={YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE} />
```

You can see in the [docs examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-of-a-specific-user-depending-on-props) how ownProps should be used